# Can i check if a json got a determinated structure?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, structure

I want to check if the json that I'm passing to my Spring project got more values than the ones it should have.

Here is the json im passing

```
{
    "ThisIsMadeUp": "Bananas",
    "summary": "summary",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in interdum ligula. Maecenas nec pellentesque orci. Sed auctor nulla nequ , sollicitudin imperdiet libero volutpat eu.",
    "raised": "2019-07-01T03:18:46Z",
    "issueType": "INCIDENT",
    "priority": "Medium"
}
```

with the "ThisIsMadeUp" field.

The thing is, that when i pass this field, everything works correctly when it must throw an error, it goes correctly because the rest of the fields are necessary to building it.

There's a way to check before the object is builded if I'm passing this field?

Comment: Why don't you check null or empty condition.

Comment: Make a list of the fields that are allowed, parse the json, iterate over the fields and see if the parsed field is contained in the allowed list.

Comment: okey, ill make the list and see how it works, thank you, when i try it i'll say if worked

Comment: Try to write custom annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some code or use one of available libraries for validating json object. You can check this one https://validatejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write some code validating this object or use one of available libraries for validating json object.

I don't like to do this, but could you just google: "json schema validator java" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to validate your schema

1. Write custom code to validate the schema using any of the JSON libraries.
2. Use existing schema validator

For creating the schema from a POJO class, you can use [jackson-module-jsonSchema](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) library

I used [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator), but this library is no longer maintained.